# Displayng menu description under main-menu links

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I am trying to display the menu description under menu links for the main-menu in my custom theme. I have tried overriding the function as given in this post http://fusiondrupalthemes.com/forum/using-fusion/descriptions-under-main-menu #10 comment, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Are you open to using a module for it? And do you mean a link description or the description of the entire menu?

Comment: Each links have its own description like in this link http://www.liberlabs.com/msm . Yes, am ready to use a module to make this functionally possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I used the Main Menu block in header region.

It wasn't working before because the Main Menu was directly being output in the page.tpl.php file by a call to `theme('links_system_main_menu')`. I followed the instructions on ["Descriptions under main menu" at the Fusion Themes forum](http://fusiondrupalthemes.com/forum/using-fusion/descriptions-under-main-menu#comment-3759), and enabled the Main Menu block to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

The changes must be done in the "Main Menu" block, not in links_system_main_menu.

Comment: I need this functionality in the main-menu which is being output in the page.tpl.php , its not a block.Is it possible to do it with a block?

Comment: He means that it's being output with a block. Go to the Blocks page and you will see "Primary links" or "Main menu" - click the **configure** link and see if you can change the description.

Comment: I can change the description at "Home » Administration » Structure » Menus" no option in blocks page. But by default its not being output. Also the main_menu block is disabled and the navigation links are being output in the the page.tpl.php by `theme('links__system_main_menu', array(_arguments_));` function.